# Change scale in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: display, 20.04, scaling

I want to have a bigger scale in Ubuntu 20.04, but I just found an option of changing the text's scale. I want that all the elements in the screen to be bigger. I want to change the scale not the resolution

The output of`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` is x11

The native resolution is 1366x768
I have enabled this option but nothing happens
[image]

Comment: What is the native resolution of your display?

Comment: @sc608 I've edit the answer

Comment: What is the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: the outout is x11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the Settings>Display GUI to enable fractional scaling, as you have done, the setting for org.gnome.mutter experimental-features is being changed from the default value to "x11-randr-fractional-scaling" (for X11 sessions) immediately.  It appears, in your case,  the setting is not being changed through the GUI.  You may want to try changing the setting via the dconf editor `sudo apt install dconf-editor` or by running the equivalent gsettings command.  The gsettings command is `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"`

Since your computer is behaving abnorally via the GUI I would proceed with caution.

Once Fractional Scaling is enabled you may want to try a setting of 1.25 to start with and adjust from there.

You may need to restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

If you want to back out of these changes issue `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "[]"` in a terminal session.

Comment: I did it but nothing happens, i'm thinking if it could be due the resolution or the screen size

Comment: I think you may be right although I can't find any reference indicating that your monitor's native resolution is incompatible with fractional scaling...  Have you tried logging into the Wayland session?

Comment: The only thing likely I found is changing the text's scale, in gnome tweaks

Answer (score 0):

I installed Gnome Tweaks, enabled the fractional scaling and logged in in the wayland sesion, then in the Gnome tweaks app I changed the scale in the typography tab, It changed the size af all the elements

Answer (score 0):

1. Change wayland to xorg
2. To Show Monitor name 
   $ xrandr --listmonitors 
   Monitors: 1 
   0: +*eDP-1 1366/344x768/193+0+0  eDP-1
3. To Reduce Monitor scale 
   $ xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1.25x1.25